# How to split array into three arrays by index?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, split

I have an array of 9 elements(maybe more).
I need to split by indexes into three arrays.

```
const array = [{id: 0}, {id: 1}, ..., {id: 8}];
```

I want to recieve 3 array like that:

```
const array0 = [{id: 0}, {id: 3}, {id: 6}];
const array1 = [{id: 1}, {id: 4}, {id: 7}];
const array2 = [{id: 2}, {id: 5}, {id: 8}];
```

Comment: What's the actual logic behind the splitting? And what have you tried?

Comment: What do you want to happen if there are more than 9 elements?

Comment: `const array0, const array1` etc, doesn't fit with your `(maybe more)` part, you possible want an array of array's instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take the remainfer of the index with three and address the dame group for every third element.

If necessary take [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), like

```
[array0, array1, array2] = result;
```

```js
const
    array = [{ id: 0 }, { id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }, { id: 4 }, { id: 5 }, { id: 6 }, { id: 7 }, { id: 8 }],
    result = array.reduce((r, o, i) => ((r[i % 3] = r[i % 3] || []).push(o), r), []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `filter()` the array using remainder operator `%`. For `array1` check if the `id % 3 === 0` and `id % 3 === 1`, `id % 3 === 2` for next ones respectively

```js
const array = Array(9).fill().map((x, i) => ({id: i}));

const array1 = array.filter(x => x.id % 3 === 0);
const array2 = array.filter(x => x.id % 3 === 1);
const array3 = array.filter(x => x.id % 3 === 2);

console.log('array1', array1)
console.log('array2', array2)
console.log('array3', array3)
```